# joining subquery that selects data from pl/sql function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

1. I need to join that subquery because it returns more than one row.
2. The joining subquery looks like(I don't know the exact syntax):

   ```
   select * from some_pl_sql_function(id_arg)
   ```
3. I need to join it with id_arg which is column of some table.
4. The function returns arrayofstrings.

The final version should looks like (I guess):

```
select * from some_table
left outer join (select * from some_pl_sql_function(id_arg)) sub_query
    on some_table.id_arg = sub_query.id_arg
```

What should I write in subquery for this to work?

Comment: can you please provide the example data and code

Answer (score 1):

If your `arrayofstrings` (the returned type of your function) is defined in schema level, ie-

```
create or replace type arrayofstrings as table of varchar2(32767);
```

Then you can use your function like this:

```
select id_arg, column_value from table(some_pl_sql_function(id_arg))
```